# Von welchem Fall wird die Präposition "bis" begleitet?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Ich habe in meinem Handbuch und im Internet folgendes gelesen betreffend die Präposition "bis":

> wenn auf "bis" eine Nominalphrase folgt, soll diese dem Akkusativ entsprechend dekliniert werden.

Ich finde mit Google aber auch Beispiele von Sätzen die dieser Behauptung widersprechen:

> bis welchem alter, bis dem Jahresende, und so weiter.

Was haltet ihr davon? Ist die Theorie wie ich sie gefunden habe ungenau, stimmen die Sätze die ich gefunden haben nicht, oder mache ich einen Interpretationsfehler?

---

Die vollständigen Sätze die ich im Internet gefunden habe:

- Bis welchem Alter ist man berufsschulpflichtig?
- Bis welchem Alter benutzt man einen Buggy?
- Ab welchem/bis welchem Alter kann man diesen Anhänger benutzen?
- Wellenreiten lernen ab / bis welchem Alter sinnvoll?
- Bis welchem Alter kann eine Katze Kitten bekommen?
- Die Augennetzhaut entwickelt sich bis dem vierten Monat des Lebens.
- Die Haspeslagh Büros und Lager in Lichtervelde bleiben bis dem Jahresende geöffnet.

Es gibt noch viel weiteres zu finden.

Comment: Wenn ich "bis dem Jahresende" google, mit Anführungszeichen, bekomme ich 9 Treffer.

Comment: Für das letzte Beispiel könnte relevant sein, dass Lichtervelde in Belgien liegt ;)

Comment: Keiner der Beispielsätze ist korrekt, es muss überall *bis zu* statt *bis* heißen, *bis zu dem* wird allerdings zu *bis zum* verkürzt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solche Regeln können (,auch wenn sie richtig sind,) für Verwirrung sorgen. In diesem Fall spielt die Präposition ["zu"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zu) eine Rolle und "fordert" den Dativ.

---

Beispiele mit "bis" + "zu" + Dativ:

> Bis zu (!) welchem Alter *(darf man wählen?)*

> Bis zum (!) Jahresende *(darfst du wählen!)*

> Bis zum nächsten Donnerstag (...)

Beispiel mit "bis" + Akkusativ:

> Bis einen Tag *(vor der Wahl ...)*

> Der Zug fährt bis (nach) Hamburg.

> Bis nächsten Donnerstag (...)

---

**deine Beispielsätze aus dem Internet**

*Ohne die fett markierten Zusätze, sind die Sätze nicht grammatikalisch korrekt.*

> Bis **zu** welchem Alter ist man berufsschulpflichtig?

> Bis **zu** welchem Alter benutzt man einen Buggy?

> Ab welchem/bis **zu** welchem Alter kann man diesen Anhänger benutzen?

> Wellenreiten lernen **ist** ab / bis **zu** welchem Alter sinnvoll?

> Bis **zu** welchem Alter kann eine Katze *Kitten* bekommen?

> Die Augennetzhaut entwickelt sich bis **zum**  vierten Monat des Lebens.

> Die Haspeslagh Büros und Lager in Lichtervelde bleiben bis **zum** Jahresende geöffnet.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort. Wenn ich es richtig verstanden habe, gilt manchmal die Kombination "bis" + dat als richtiges Deutsch weil "bis" üblicherweise von "zu" gefolgt wird, auch wenn "zu" nicht in dem Sätz steht von denen die Rede ist? Das wirft neue Fragen bei mir auf. Hat diese Erscheining einen Namen womit ich mit Google herausfinden kann wie es funktioniert? Ich Zweifle jetzt an allem was ich glaubte von den Deutschen Fällen zu verstehen.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin Kannst du die vollständigen Beispielsätze in deiner Frage ergänzen? "Bis welchem Alter" und "bis dem Jahresende" kann ich im Moment nicht zuordnen.

Comment: Ich habe einige Beispielsätze hinzugefügt.

Comment: Ich schätze ihre Bemühungen sehr, aber ich verstehe noch immer nicht wie ich dieses "Geschehen" mit dem abwesenden "zu" einordnen soll, beziehungsweise die Frage die ich am Anfang gestellt habe ist bisher ungelöst geblieben. Soll ich die Konstruktion "bis" + dat wie in den Beispielen gezeigt als einen weit verbreiteten Fehler betrachten? Oder hängt das ganze etwa mit regionaler Sprachvariation zusammen, wie @Carsten S darauf hingedeutet hat? Es verunsichert mich das eine Regel die in einem Handbuch steht nicht mit der Praksis übereinstimmt. Ist es etwa die Regel die ich falsch verstanden habe?

Comment: Die Sätze sind nicht grammatisch korrekt. Es fehlt das "zu". Wenn das aber nicht benötigt wird, gilt die Regel, die Sie dargestellt haben..

Comment: Ach so! Könntet Ihr das bitte am Anfang Ihrer Antwort vermelden? Ich glaube es könnte diesen "Post" begreiflicher machen für spätere Leser.
Vielleicht sollten wir dazu auch ein paar Kommentare löschen.
Ich bin zufrieden zu sehen das dieser Knoten irgendwie gelöst ist.